How to reduce inference time and restrict additional information generation in Meta-Llama-3-8b model?
I have deployed the Meta-Llama-3-8b model on my server using Xinference. Everything is working good, however the inference time is about 16 seconds even for simple prompts, also it generates extra and additional information (garbage) which is not required. I would like to have some help in this regard on how to reduce inference and avoid generation of extra information. I have thrice checked the compatibility of my hardware, it's fine to run the model smoothly. I believe that there must be something I have to change in configuration files, but have no idea how to do it. Please let me know if someone has any solution to this problem.
I have tried to change the prompt, and guide the model to not generate extra information but it won't work at all. I am expecting the model to quickly respond and generate only those information which are required rather than generating extra information.
Please let me know as quickly as possible if someone has come across such a problem. Thanks!

Try this https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/mastering-llm-techniques-inference-optimization/
Also you can try hf tgi
Take gpu with high memory bandwidth
